# Android and BufferedImage issue

Tags: android, bitmap, bufferedimage

I recently read that I cannot use `BufferedImage` in Android. This means that I cannot use the libraries I used in the past for applying effects to images.

I would like to ask what are the Android libraries available to apply effects to `Bitmap` ?

Comment: what have you researched so far ?

Comment: @HowardPautz I found `JJIL` and `Aviary` and `Java CV`. I guess I am going with Java CV :) Anything else you know of ?